# sort all items except for the first item (li)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I found it's not workable when I select li and use sortable().. it work when I apply it on my ul

```
$('ul').sortable();
```

but how to avoid the first one to be sorted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use items attribute for sortable function. Below code will solve your problem
and the first li would be avoided to be included in sortable functionality.

```
$('ul').sortable({items: 'li:not(:first)'});
```

Comment: You can use `{}` button to set the code highlight, it will append 4 spaces before each line of the code.

Comment: {} button? what is that?

Answer (score 1):

Add "ui-state-disabled" class to first li. Sorting will be disabled for that li

```
<li class="ui-state-disabled">sorting Disabled for this li</li>
```